# FUELPHP - Changing the name of the "public" folder

Tags: configuration, directory, public, fuelphp

in my public folder is called "public_html", so I wonder how can I configurate fuel to use the "public_html" instead of the "public"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special, just rename the `public` folder to `public_html`.

The contents of the `public` folder include the remaining components of the framework, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to rename the `public` folder to `public_html`.

Answer (score 1):

Is your webservers docroot pointed to public_html ?

Fuel isn't doing anything special with the public directory it's just where the initial http request is picked up.